# Maven leaving jar libraries empty

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

I have an ejb containing 2 jar and a war, when I execute the maven clean install of each project, on my server (JBoss Wildfly 12.0.0) it leaves the jar folders empty.

I have checked my .m2 and there are compiled, and not empty.

This are my dependencies at the war `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>es.project.backend.interface</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-interface</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>es.project.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you automated the deployment with jbosstools or some other plugin and bound this goal to the install phase or some other phase it depends on? Otherwise you shouldn't expect maven to deploy to your server, the install phase is meant to install in a maven repo, not on an application server. Same for the deploy phase, it is meant to deploy to a remote repository.

Comment: I have manually installed each project, then compiled the war app. In the war, the jars remains empty @Aaron

Comment: Can you make sure the dependencies to yours jars in your war's pom aren't in `<scope>provided</scope>` ?

Comment: It is not. If I press full publish under the library dependence at my server. It copies the correct folders again, that's why I think I am missing a step before.

Comment: Care to post your war's pom? Also I'm not sure I correctly understand your context ; in particular : that jar folder, it's the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory inside the war, right? You're building your projects (starting by the jars) with `maven clean install`, but the war package that results from that doesn't contain the jars, right?

Comment: It contains the folders, but empty. I `maven clean install` the jars, then the war, and publish it on server. Edited question to post pom.xml

Comment: You should add the maven-war-plugin configuration too probably, the dependencies have nothing wrong with them at least

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182018/discussion-between-pablo-casas-and-aaron).